# Patent Office uspto-pair PAIR data on storage.google.com OR commondatastorage.google.com

Tags: c#, http

The US Patent Office makes PUBLIC data available on the Google Cloud.

Can anyone provide insight why the request fails? Is an Authorization header really necessary for this?

My app sends the following request for a tsv file:

```
 GET /uspto-pair/applications/12394128-transaction_history.tsv HTTP/1.1
 Host: commondatastorage.googleapis.com 
 Authorization: GOOG1
 GOOGLES3EYEOH7Y5DJQS:0�;ס��6a��b��7� 
 Content-Length: 0
 x-goog-api-version: 1 
 Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2013 12:41:43 GMT
```

Here is the Response from Google:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 1 2013 16:36:58 (1364859418) 
Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2013 12:41:53 GMT
Expires: Sat, 06 Apr 2013 12:41:53 GMT 
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 
Content-Length: 0 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

503 means

> The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.

Answer (score 0):

The individual .tsv file is not available for download. If you change the path to /uspto-pair/applications/12394128.zip it should work.